# GAMS Binary Variable Logic Decision

Tags: binary, logic, gams-math

i got a problem with my GAMS modelling (linear problem, no multiplication of binary variables allowed).
I'd like to have three binary variables where the first value depends on the other two.

The value table is given below (v1=x if (v2=y **and** v3=z))

```
 V1 | V2 | V3
----+----+----
  1 |  1 |  1
  0 |  1 |  0
  0 |  0 |  1
  0 |  0 |  0
```

So v1 is 1 only if both v2 and v3 are 1. How can I turn this behavior into equations in gams where v1, v2 and v3 are binary variables?

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following three equations together should do the trick:

```
e1.. v1 =g= v2 + v3 - 1;
e2.. v1 =l= v2;
e3.. v1 =l= v3;
```

Comment: thank you. i think it's possible to combine e2 and e3 to
e2.. 2*v1 =l= v2 + v3;

right?